# How do I prevent attributes of a class that are objects from changing outside the class?

Tags: java

If I have a Person class that has an attribute of type Car, and I have a setter that passes the car to the attribute through a simple assignment, as follows:

Person.java

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private Car car;

    //getter and setter for name
    //....
    
    public void getCar(){
        return this.car;
    }
    public Car setCar(Car car){
        this.car = car;
    }
}
```

Car.java

```
public class Car {
    private String brand;

    //getters and setters for brand
}
```

How can I prevent a copy being made to the attribute when passing the car through the setter, ensuring that the parameter passed externally when modified does not cause changes within the Person object?

Comment: One solution is to clone the object passed into the setter rather than just assigning directly.

Comment: Or better, use a copy-constructor, since clone really should be avoided. But having said this, this sounds like an XY Problem. Why do you need this? Is the problem on the other end -- that you're not creating new instances of Car where you should be doing so?

Comment: Many people have suggested, correctly, that you should make a copy or clone of the Car object, both in getCar and setCar.  This practice occurs quite frequently in Java SE classes, and is known as *defensive copying.*

Answer (score 3):

The Car could have a `mileage` which would be a mutable, shared field that others might update.

However if Car is a snapshot, say for publishing for selling, you want the class Car to be **immutable**.

You could do that by making a *deep copy* of Car and object fields recursively. Java knows the Object method `clone()` for that. But cloning is a bit deprecated, as it by-passes constructors.

There are immutable classes like String. These can be shared: assigned directly.
A systematic immutable class is provided by the `record` class:

```
public record Point(int x, int y) { }

Point pt = new Point(3, 4);
int gridDistance = pt.x() + pt.y();
```

Furthermore collections have often an `unmodifiable...` wrapper class in `Collections`.

Comment: This I like better. Make "that which should not be changed"™ unchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... How can I prevent a copy being made to the attribute when passing the car through the setter, ensuring that the parameter passed externally when modified does not cause changes within the Person object?"*

One approach is to create a *static* method within the class, to define what gets copied.

```java
public class Car {
    private String brand;

    //getters and setters for brand
    
    static Car copy(Car c) {
        Car copy = new Car();
        copy.brand = c.brand;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Then when passing it as a parameter, send the copy.

```java
Car c = new Car("brand");
Person p = new Person("name", Car.copy(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an object to a method, you are actually passing the reference to that object and not the object itself. So - when you are setting the car attribute of the Person class, you are not creating a new copy of the Car object, you are just pointing to the existing one.

Your Car class is actually quiet immutable now, unless you want to modify a Car instance by changing its brand? I suppose you will add more fields to your class, so if you want to ensure that changes to the Car object outside of the Person class don't affect the Car object inside the Person class, you can create a new copy of Car object and pass it to the setter method of Person instance. Here's how you can do it:

add constructor to Car which will copy previous instance of the Car object. Copy constructor is (almost) good idea because its in the Car class which knows best what to copy:

```
public class Car {
    private String brand;
    public Car(Car car) {
        this.brand = car.brand;
    }

    //...
}

Parson p = new Person();
p.setCar(new Car(someCar)); // Setting someCar copy
```

This way, the Car object inside the Person class is a different object from the one passed to the setCar method, and changes to one won't affect the other. What you want here is a deep copy of the instance of Car type, so if you will ever add more complicated objects inside your Car class, then you will make sure they are also deep copied.

From my perspective such deep copying of objects look bad in java, you can finally end up with some SO suggestions to use reflection for creating deep copies (I have seen such using gson lib). If your aim is to assign a new car to each person, then you may think of writing a factory class which will create new Car instances of specified parameters. Read more on Factory method pattern on wiki.

Answer (score -1):

Your concern is valid. Any changes made to the `Car` object that is passed to `Person.setCar()` will be reflected inside the `Person` instance since the `car` is a reference. One way to prevent this is to clone it in the setter:

```
this.car = car.clone();
```

I think you will need to `implements Cloneable` on the `Car` class to allow this.

Comment: 1) Cloning has issues, and should in general be avoided and certainly not recommended, but more importantly, 2) I still don't see how their concern is valid. If a Car object has been created, then changes to the state of that same Car object should be reflected in all references. If a new object is needed, then one should be created, but not in setter method. That could cause significant problems down the line.